# Errors in Vapor setup on Ubuntu 14.04 (Windows)

Tags: swift, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vapor

Following steps from https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/install-toolbox.html are leaded to this error:

`$ curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash`

> /swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift-build: error while loading shared libraries: libFoundation.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in Ubuntu on Windows?

Comment: @tobygriffin yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Ubuntu on Windows to check with, but this is a [known issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2700).

[This commenter](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/916#issuecomment-263081366) on GitHub appears to have found a solution.

```
apt-get install execstack
execstack -c {swift_path}/usr/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so
```

Comment: Needs `sudo execstack...`